# app not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue

Tags: facebook, authentication

I got this error on the Facebook page.

`App not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue. you will be able to log in when the app is reactivated.`

Also, I was implement facebook login in the Laravel with "Laravel Socialite".

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73519223/6381711) help?

Comment: Make sure that you logged out your previous facebook account on the current browser.

Comment: @gsharew that worked for me. I was unknowingly logged into Facebook as a user who was not an approved test user for the app. When I logged out, the error went away.

Comment: @gsharew Worked for me too! In my case I migrated to a new facebook app in the same flutter project and that gave me the error

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's happened because your app on Facebook for developers website is not active

solution

1. go to Facebook for developers from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/?no_redirect=1)
2. choose My Apps from the top bar
3. click on your app icon ( then you will notice that your app is not active from the top bar )
4. from the left side select settings >> basic
5. put your privacy policy link in the Privacy Policy URL and in the User data deletion field, you can make a copy from [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L3Z6P6a5AIC0cWBOBIHd9XOR1gqQruOo6hmM99TtVYM/edit?usp=sharing) privacy policy ( to make a copy from the privacy policy select file from the top bar and select make a copy )
6. press save changes

I hope that it was helpful

Comment: Can you please help me, I don't see any `User data deletion field`

Comment: The user data deletion field is below the Privacy Policy URL , check step number 4

Comment: Be aware that when your app is inactive, the owner of the app can still login, as if the app was active. IMO that's misleading, expecially for indie devs that work alone. A developer could think everything is operating normally while only she can login.

Comment: hi how to do bussiness verfication , i am only try to test facbook login in my flutter app but now it is continiouslly asking to verify the business

Comment: @Omar, I added a privacy policy link as well as user data deletion link. Though when I try to do a facebook login. It says "app not active". Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 12):

The error suggests your Facebook app is not active; it should definitely be in Development Mode.

You get that error because the Facebook user account you are using to test the login with Facebook feature is neither added to your Facebook app as an Administrative nor Developer account.

You should check and ensure the Facebook user account meets either condition above.

Alternatively, you can change you App Mode from Deployment to Live, if you are ready to make it accessible to your users.

Comment: how to change it ? the option is not showing until app review is done

Answer (score 2):

2023/8/9 latest solution

You don't need to set your app to 'active' if you're only testing the login functionality.
The issue you're facing likely arises because you're using a Facebook account that isn't whitelisted as a test account.

1. **The easiest solution** :
   The login account must be the same as your developer account, not any other Facebook account
2. add another account to your whitelist:
   Go to your app on the Meta developer console, **under 'App Roles'-> 'Roles'**, add a new Facebook account

Answer (score 1):

Go to developers.facebook.com/apps/**your-app-id**/app-review/permissions

Change **public_profile**  to **Advanced Access**.

Thats all.

Comment: Seems to be outdated info.. it redirects to cases and no such thing as Advanced Access.

Comment: @Jack0fshad0ws go to developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app. There you will see on left side menu Dashboard/Settings/App Roles/Alerts/App Review. Open App Review and find on the page "public_profile".

Answer (score 0):

In the development mode you should add the user in App roles -> Roles.
When adding users make sure they have active FB development account. Otherwise facebook just closes the window without any error message.

[image]