# Getting issue in Flutter app in Facebook login feature

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-login, flutter-facebook-login

I am using flutter 1.22.5 and Facebook plugin **flutter_facebook_login: 3.0.0**

to provide feature of Sign in with Facebook. Currently facing this error.

**App not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue. you will be able to log in when the app is reactivated**

For other dependency I am not allowed to update flutter or Facebook plugin version.

Can someone guide me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328805/19977117) is recent and may help. The error may not be linked to your code, but I recommend that you try to update your code to a SDK [latest Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases) version.

Comment: Yes, I update privacy policy details. Still it won't work for me. And I mention in question I am not allowed to upgrade sdk version.