# Could not able to login into facebook using the passport js in nextjs app

Tags: javascript, passport.js, next.js13, passport-facebook

I have added passport js to my application and tried to implement the facebook login using that npm package.But after login to the facebook im getting the below issue from the facebook.Can anyone help?
[Error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a3R9.png)

Configuration image in meta developer account:[Config image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ4kV.png)

Expecting the response after login from the facebook

Comment: Go to [Meta for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) and activate your app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hii https://stackoverflow.com/users/14945696/kevin-m-mansour
 How to activate the app ? can you explain me ?

Comment: @k.ashoksagar (Just write `@KevinM.Mansour` to mention me properly.) [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328805/14945696)

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `next-auth` package or `clerck` will fit all your needs, so I highly recommend you use one of them instead of using `passport` package.