# Flutter facebook login

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, visual-studio-code, android-app-signing

First time when i click on login with facebook I got the pop up with id password input field
then after that everytime I click on login with facebook
I got following error message

App not active: This app is not accessible right now and the app developer is aware of the issue. You will be able to log in when the app is reactivated

I restarted the debug session as well thinking that it will allow me to enter new id pw so that I can test with same developer account but nothing happens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [app not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73193526/app-not-active-this-app-is-not-currently-accessible-and-the-app-developer-is-aw)